# How does Hemocytoblast constantly get formed into so many blood cells and yet remains there in the bone marrow throughout the lifetime?

Tags: hematology, blood-circulation, red-blood-cell

I mean, Hemocytoblast is a stem cell which is constantly being differentiated into daughter cells and leads to formation of all the blood cells (having short and limited life spans), so how come those stem cells remain there and continue to function, even when we grow up and finally grow old (i.e for 70 years approx)? The no. of those stem cells gotta be limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick for the stem cells lies in the way the proliferate and differentiate. See the image (from the reference 1):

[image]

Stem cells have the problem that they need to differentiate and maintain their population at the same time (subfigure a). This can either be done by asymmetric cell division which leads to one daughter which is still a stem cell and one which has been differentiated (subfigure b). Then it is possible that the cells divide only symmetrical (as shown in subfigure c) so they will either deliver two stem cells or two differentiated cells. And then it is possible (shown in subfigure d) that both possibilities are mixed and that symmetrical and assymetrical division occurs. Either way you get both: Differentiated cells and you still manage to maintain the stem cell pool.

References:

1. [Asymmetric and symmetric stem-cell divisions in development and
   cancer](https://biochem.wisc.edu/sites/default/files/people/judith-kimble/pdfs/2000s/100s/134_Morrison_Kimble_2006.pdf)
2. [Asymmetric cell division of stem and progenitor cells during
   homeostasis and cancer](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00018-013-1386-1)
3. [Asymmetric cell division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_cell_division)

Comment: your first link is broken

Comment: Can this asymmetric cell division be defined as mitosis?

Comment: Is this the only way, how these stem cells remain active for so many years? I don't think, that even with your answer taken into account, that's possible if we consider 70 years of average life span.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the notification, I fixed this.

Comment: @a.aniq yes, it's mitosis. What else would it be? Also, since these cells **do** remain active for an entire lifetime, your assumptions need to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Yes, this happens via mitosis. The cells most likely get additional signalling when they differentiate in this process which is different from the signals they get when they should maintain their stem cell properties.

Comment: From where do they get the signals?

Comment: They get them from the environment, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation) for some basics.

Comment: Data shows [lipid metabolism](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1550413112003713) is a big factor in determining how the stem cells differentiate.